# Qt quick 2 paint method doesn't get called

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created a simple Qt quick application and I have an issue drawing with QQuickPaintedItem.
I checked in debug mode if the paint gets called, but doesn't.
Anyway here's my code:

Source:

```
ParticleHandler::ParticleHandler(QQuickPaintedItem *parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents);
    particle = new Particle();
}
void ParticleHandler::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen = QPen(m_color);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->drawEllipse(particle->Position.x,particle->Position.y,particle->Radius/2,particle->Radius/2);
}
```

Header:

```
ParticleHandler(QQuickPaintedItem *parent = 0);
void paint(QPainter *painter);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the width and height of your custom item.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Fizika 1.0
Rectangle
{
  width: 360
  height: 360
  Particle
    { 
     width: 100
     height: 100
     radius: 20
     x: 100
     y: 200
     color: "red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Horrible, somehow works for me after introducing width and height.

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious without seeing the rest of the code what the main problem is, but here's a fully self-contained example. Maybe it'll help.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtQuick>

class PaintedItem : public QQuickPaintedItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PaintedItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent) {
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter) {
        painter->fillRect(contentsBoundingRect(), Qt::red);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<PaintedItem>("mymodule", 1, 0, "PaintedItem");

    QQuickView view(QUrl("qrc:///qml/main.qml"));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.resize(500, 500);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

And the contents of main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import mymodule 1.0

Rectangle {
    color: "black"

    PaintedItem {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 50
        height: 50
    }
}
```

Comment: It basically looks like your code except of the differences in the constructor:
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents);
    particle = new Particle();

Comment: Are you sure your constructor is even being called i.e. that you don't have some problem with registering your type?

Comment: And that flag is irrelevant as QQuickPaintedItem sets that flag itself in its constructor.

Comment: I'm checking if it's called and it's called.

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to help. Can you share the code where you register your type and the actual QML?

Comment: The QML:
`import QtQuick 2.0
import Fizika 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Particle
    {
        radius: 20
        x: 100
        y: 200
        color: "red"
    }
}
`
The main.cpp:
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<ParticleHandler>("Fizika", 1, 0,"Particle");
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Utkozes/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `update()` at some point, which will schedule a repaint.

As a unrelated side note, be careful about threading - paint() is called from the render thread, so you need proper syncronization for things like `particle`.

Comment: Where should I call an `Update`?

Comment: Call update() in the constructor to trigger the first paint, and later call update() when you need a repaint

Comment: I added update() to the constructor but paint does not get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line after the class declaration

> QML_DECLARE_TYPE(ParticleHandler)